Из-за чего могут подлагивать анимации в Qt Widgets?
При работе в проекте с Qt Animation Framework (QAbstractAnimation) простые анимации перемещения или изменения прозрачности подлагивают. Это хорошо видно на анимации QScroller(внутри используется QAbstractAnimation). Из-за чего они могут возникать и как добиться плавности БЕЗ ПЕРЕХОДА НА QML? Qt Widgets. Может ли это связано с тем, что все рендерится на процессоре и надо переносить виджеты на OpenGl?
